# From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the endpoint?

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, containers, docker-network

I have a cloudwatch agent installed in EC2 instance and also a docker image on the instance.
From the EC2 instance, I could successfully send out logs to endpoint(0.0.0.0:25888) to cloudwatch. But when I get into the docker image using `docker exec -it <container id> bash`, I tried to publish same logs from inside container but it failed with following error:

```
2861 2022-07-21 00:11:18,686 ERROR (10.0.1.124,1385:MainThread) aws_embedded_metrics.sinks.tcp_client: Failed to connect to the socket. [Errno 111] Connection refused
2862 2022-07-21 00:11:18,686 INFO (10.0.1.124,1385:MainThread) aws_embedded_metrics.sinks.agent_sink: Parsed agent endpoint (tcp) 0.0.0.0:25888
```

Wondering if anyone knows the root cause here or any debugging clue? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I run into this as well. My solution (workaround?) was to:

1. Make sure the cloudwatch agent is listening on `udp://0.0.0.0:25888` and not `127.0.0.1` (the default). The CWAgent docs I have seen don't have any examples on how to achieve this.
2. Once inside the container, use the Docker host IP to send messages. For me this was `export AWS_EMF_AGENT_ENDPOINT=udp://172.17.0.1:25888`, as I was using `aws-embedded-metrics-python`. YMMV depending on the underlying library that you use.